# Parse.com dead before January 2017?

Tags: parse-platform

We're heavy user of Parse.com for more than 2 years now (Android, iOS and Web clients). Since January 2016, we have a lot of errors coming from Parse, in particular when we write data (and mostly between 9AM-10PM, US time).

Do you have any ideas on how to fix that? Note that we are paying users (we're not using the "free" parse.com...).

They might want us to leave as quickly as possible, but before being able to do that, the quality of service is really poor. And when you have real users on your Apps, that's not cool...

Some examples of the issues we have:

Uncaught TypeError: no method _isNullOrUndefined

[image]

Request timed out:

[image]

Uncaught undefined:

[image]

Your help is very welcome to understand how we could fix that (and if you experience the same issues?).

---

**EDIT March 29th, 2016**

We moved our databases to MongoLab (keeping Parse on Parse.com for now), and 99% of these errors vanished.

Comment: If you pay then you can send a support request and expect a response

Comment: We are getting exactly the same issues with our app (cloud jssdk 1.6.14). Suddenly a huge amount of `Result: Uncaught null` or `Result: Uncaught undefined` or `Result: Execution timed out`  responses to cloud functions...

Comment: I see there is a more recent release (1.7.1) available on github, although this has not been published on the main Parse site : https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-JS/releases

Comment: We have the same type of issues on iOS/Android unfortunately, and I don't believe client libs can fix that, don't you think? It looks like a pure server issue.

Comment: as I understood it (but I am probably wrong) Cloud code is just a version of the jssdk running on node... hence my hope that the Parse-SDK guys would help - but it turns out they can't

Comment: read my edit above, it might help you.

Comment: @Tom-Lunabee.com this may be coincidental - i have notices that 99% or our errors have also disappeared now - and we haven't moved off Parse.com yet